# i am unable to decode json object in php

Tags: java, php, json

here is my java code and it makes an http request and send json object to php script.

login.java

```
    String username = jTextField1.getText();
    String password = jPasswordField1.getText();

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

    obj.put("username", username);
    obj.put("password", password);

    //JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
    //list.add(username);
    //list.add(password);


    //obj.put("logindata", list);
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/kolitha/json_test/index.php");
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity("myjson" + obj.toString());
        httppost.setEntity(se);
        System.out.print(se);
        httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        System.out.println(obj.toString());

        //response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://localhost/kolitha/json_test/index.php");
        response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));



    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.print("Cannot establish connection!");

    }
```

this is my index.php script and i am unable to extract username and password from the json object.

index.php

```
$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

$username=$obj->{'username'};
$password=$obj->{'password'};


$connect=mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
IF (!$connect){
die ('Failed Connecting to Database: ' . mysql_error());}

$d = mysql_select_db("kolitha_json_test");
if(!$d){ echo "db not selected";}

$sql="SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' ";
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

 // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1)
{
echo "true";
}
else
 {
echo "false";
}
?>
```

Comment: what thus your json looks like?

Comment: i don't understand what you ask?

Comment: Can you please post output of `var_dump($obj)`

Comment: If json_decode() fails, then it is likely not valid json that you are giving it. Please echo out the json and add it to your question

Comment: isn't your json prefixed with `StringEntity se = new StringEntity("myjson" + obj.toString());` `myjson` ? that would break the json woundn't it

Comment: var_dump out put NULL

Comment: kolitha error eka in the javacode

Comment: what is the result of `file_get_contents('php://input')`??? Do you have used the right path?

Comment: i don't think it's the java code and can you point it out.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i left a comment but no one seems to pay attention to a comment. The error is in the Java Code

```
StringEntity se = new StringEntity("myjson" + obj.toString());
```

which adds a prefix to the json string called `myjson`

Comment: can you please explain how it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Why are Using both **HttpPost**  and **HttpGet.** You are adding string entity to **HttpPost** request and **not using it**..

whereas you are using **Httpget** where you have **not set** ur username and  password(so obviously there is no json data associated with httpget request)

Make changes here

```
 response = httpclient.execute(httppost);//don comment this line
```

Add comment hereif you are using httppost

```
//HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://localhost/kolitha/json_test/index.php");
//response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
```

Comment: thanks shanku.i corrected it.but it still doesn't work properly.